# URL Rewrite xml to rss

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, rss

I have a feed.xml file containing my RSS feed and I'd like to rewrite the url example.com/feed.xml to example.com/feed.rss.

I've tried with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^feed.xml$ feed.rss [L]
```

But it doesn't work. When I access the feed.xml, it displays the feed and when I access the feed.rss I have an Error 404.

I know that is possible but I think something is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1):

Just swap the pattern and substitution in your `RewriteRule` directive:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^feed\.rss$ /feed.xml [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the result is the same.

Comment: @cyclone200 Then probably your server is not loading the rewrite module. Please check: http://stackoverflow.com/q/869092/1190388

Comment: The rewrite module is active because just before I have a well working Non www to www rewrite.